# Have the default level of video tag been changed?

Tags: html, css

I used the `<video>` tag in a mobile browser project in 2019. I remember that when the `<video>` tag playing will cover the pop-up navigation drawer, because of `video` tag default level is very large on a mobile website.

But when I used a `video` tag today, I found it no longer covers other elements. And setting the `z-index` property on `video` tag will not take effect.

I don't sure `video` tag default level has changed or it's if there is an error.
I searched many articles, but couldn't find the relevant information with " video tag default level has changed".

---

ps:

This is the code for 2019：

```
<div class="video-area" :style="{ 'height': this.screenWidth * 0.56 + 'px'}">
  <video id="video"  v-show="!navShow"
         style="display: inline-block;"
         :style="{ 'height': this.screenWidth * 0.56 + 'px'}"
         :poster="require('~/assets/images/mobile/video.png')"
         loop
         preload="metadata"
         controls>
    <source src="~/assets/images/mobile/index.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <img v-show="navShow" style="width:100%;" src="~/assets/images/mobile/video.png"/>
</div>
```

css lang="scss":

```
.video-area {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your CSS has problem. Nested CSS declaration?

Comment: This css code used Sass. The style code works normally. Thanks for you correcting my English grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early smartphones had quite small screens and made the UI decision that if a webpage wanted to play a video then it would do so fullscreen. This takes it out of the browser UI so the navigation bar wouldn't be visible.

Today, smartphones tend to have screens which are large enough to display a video at a reasonable size even if it doesn't take up the whole screen. There are played inline in a webpage and UI elements of the browser will cover them up.

There was an interstitial point where screens were large enough but backwards compatibility with earlier phone behaviour was desired. The [`playsinline` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#attr-video-playsinline) was added so browsers could default to fullscreen but be switched to inline by the page author.

With inline videos, you can adjust the `z-index` to layer videos with other elements of the page (but not browser UI elements like the navigation bar) subject to the normal rules that apply to the `z-index` property (i.e. it doesn't apply to elements which aren't *positioned* and it moves the element within the stacking context of its *containing block*).

To cover up browser's UI elements you need to make the video fullscreen.